# How can individual Jupyter notebook cells be executed programmatically from .py or .ipynb files?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a complex Jupyter notebook containing code for multiple experiments depending on which cells are run. I'd like to be able **to execute a subset of cells from another script or notebook that I can run from the command line**. Everything I'm seeing would suggest using Jupyter's built-in nbconvert with TagRemovePreprocessor directives to remove cells not needed for a particular experiment (there does not seem to be equivalent white listing functionality with tags in Jupyter), however I'd like to avoid this since I'd need to change several removal tags to switch between the cells needed to run different experiments.

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to run each of the individual experiments from the command line separately. This answer ([Jupyter Notebooks: How do I execute only cells that have a particular tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50921297/jupyter-notebooks-how-do-i-execute-only-cells-that-have-a-particular-tag)) gets close, but as far as I can tell I still need to run the Javascript functions it gives in the same notebook (which I don't want to open) that I'm trying to run a subset of cells in. Is there a way to run a subset of notebook cells from an external .py script (or even an external notebook)? Jupyter magic %%run ./my_notebook.ipynb also won't work since that will run the entire notebook whereas I need to run a specific subset of cells. [nbextensions Runtime](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/runtools/readme.html?highlight=runtools) also doesn't seem to have a ready-made solution for running individual cells programmatically.

Edit: If someone knows how to do this through [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill), that would be especially useful.

Comment: This seems to be pushing the limits of what jupyter notebooks were designed for. Why not just convert the notebook into a .py file and wrap each experiment in a function, so you can easily do it the way God intended.

Comment: Because the prerequisite functions for the various experiments involve setting a large number of variables that are used by all the experiments, and I'd rather use the global workspace to transfer them lazily than to continually update function APIs as more variables are added and removed. I find it hard to believe that there is no way to programmatically make happen what I can easily do through the graphic interface: just select a specific subset of cells and run them one by one.

Comment: Just start an ipython session and import your variables from a file into the global namespace. There is nothing special happening in Jupyter that you can’t just easily do with .py files.