# Jupyter Notebooks Nbextension : Cell Filter failed to run?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[Jupyter Notebooks: How do I execute only cells that have a particular tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50921297/jupyter-notebooks-how-do-i-execute-only-cells-that-have-a-particular-tag)

It is a good topic for newbie to use the tags in cells.

But when i open the Nbextensions tab , i find another nbextension about cell_tags usage. The cell_filter nbextension.

Cell Filter

An extension that allows you to filter cells by tags. Keywords entered into the search bar separated by spaces joins them with logical AND.

section: notebook require path: cell_filter/cell_filter compatibility: 4.x, 5.x

The problem is i can not find the 'search bar' in notebooks UI after i enable this cell_filter nbextension.

How can i deal with it ?

I installed the Anaconda with python 3.8.10 on Windows 7 and used the other nbextension toc/vim normally.

I use Chrome 87.

Comment: You may have a problem with that extension because you show 'cell_filter compatibility: 4.x, 5.x' and the current version of the classic jupyter notebook is version 6, see under 'Releases' on the right side [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook).

Comment: If you are looking for an alternative, actively-developed topic that relies on tags in cells for novices of notebooks, I would suggest [RISE](https://rise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

cell_filter_search bar :
https://s1.ax1x.com/2022/04/10/LFhLSf.jpg
[image: cell_filter_search bar]

May help :
https://github.com/holzschu/Carnets/issues/154

The problem :
I edited the cell_filter.js as 'holzschu' said , but failed to take out the search_box , after restart the whold jupyter notebook yesterday.

This morning download the nbextensions package and replace the cell_filter again then edited the cell_filter.js as 'holzschu' said .

The cell_filter search_bar raised and got the searching tags result as the pic.

Jupyter notebook version : 6.4.3